# Paperclip gem support .doc uploading or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I’m able to accept uploads of `.pdf`, `.gif`, and `.jpeg`s with Paperclip, but `.doc` and `.xls` aren’t working.

The Paperclip code in the model looks like this:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

Here is the migration:

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :documents, :avatar_file_name, :string
    add_column :documents, :avatar_content_type, :string
    add_column :documents, :avatar_file_size, :integer
    add_column :documents, :avatar_updated_at, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :documents, :avatar_file_name
    remove_column :documents, :avatar_content_type
    remove_column :documents, :avatar_file_size
    remove_column :documents, :avatar_updated_at
  end
end
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Why would someone use a `.doc` or an `.xls` as their avatar?

You are telling Paperclip to make a thumbnail of the uploaded file, which won’t work for non-image-y files. If you want to allow many types of file to be uploaded but only make thumbnails for images, try [conditionally resizing](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Conditionally-resizing-images).

Comment: i m unable to upload .doc file also

Comment: What processor are you using to generate the thumbnails? ImageMagick, for instance, can’t process `.doc`s alone.

Comment: i m using imagemagick now i m able to uploads but unable to make thumnails of doc or pdf file

Comment: As far as I know, ImageMagick can’t make thumbnails of `.doc`s. As for `.pdf`s, is it because you copied the condition resizing code but didn’t add `pdf` as an accepted content type?

It’s easy enough to run ImageMagick on the command line to test whether it will be able to make a thumbnail outside of Rails.